# How would you get CCSprite current velocity as a value

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to calculate when the sprite which is affect by gravity starts to fall down. I presume I can get the velocity value for when it turns into a negative?

Is it something like this if I was trying to get the current velocity of a sprite on the Y axis?

`_sprite.physicsbody.velocity.y`

So if I had it in the `update` method

```
int velocityY = //Whatever I need to do to get the velocity.
```

Comment: You essentially posted the solution already ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both together, and use to proper data type, and you're in business:

```
CGFloat velocityY = _sprite.physicsBody.velocity.y;
if (velocityY < 0.0)
{
    // moving down ...
}
```